# CSS3 animation for rotation of an image, with parameters controlled by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation

I would like to continuously rotate an image efficiently -- it must work smoothly on mobile browsers.  I am currently using CSS3 animation.  I would like to be able to control the CSS functionality using javascript (start, stop, set rotation speed, easing for extra credit).
Here is what I have so far to do the rotation itself.  JS needed.

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<img class="image" src="https://brainful.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/images/twoStates/circle.png" alt="">
```

CSS:

```
.image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    margin:-60px 0 0 -60px;
    -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

JS: TODO

```
Rotate = {
  speed: 4,
  start: function () {
  },
  stop: function () {
  },
  setSpeed: function () {
  },
  setEasing: function () {
  }
};
```

Comment: That's as far as I've gotten.  Don't know how to make the js interact with the CSS (hence the question).  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS3 animation functionality can be manipulated by javascript, based on your question the code would be something like this.

```
    start: function () {
        var elem = document.getElementById('elementId');
        elem.style.animationPlayState = 'running';
    },
    stop: function () {
        var elem = document.getElementById('elementId');
        elem.style.animationPlayState = 'paused';
    },
    setSpeed: function (newSpeed) {
        var elem = document.getElementById('elementId');
        elem.style.animationDuration= newSpeed;
    },
    setEasing: function (newEasing) {
        var elem = document.getElementById('elementId');
        //whatever you want to change
    }
```

**Update**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <style>
    .image {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      margin: -60px 0 0 -60px;
      -webkit-animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
      -moz-animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
      animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
    }
    @-moz-keyframes spin {
      100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
    @keyframes spin {
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <img id="theImage" class="image" src="https://brainful.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/images/twoStates/circle.png" alt="">
  <button onclick="Rotate.start()">Start</button>
  <button onclick="Rotate.stop()">Stop</button>
  <button onclick="Rotate.setSpeed('1s')">Speed</button>
  <button onclick="Rotate.setEasing()">Earsing</button>
  <script>
    Rotate = {
      speed: 4,
      start: function() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('theImage');
        elem.style.animationPlayState = 'running';
      },
      stop: function() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('theImage');
        elem.style.animationPlayState = 'paused';
      },
      setSpeed: function(newSpeed) {
        var elem = document.getElementById('theImage');
        elem.style.animationDuration = newSpeed;
      },
      setEasing: function(newEasing) {
        var elem = document.getElementById('theImage');
        //whatever you want to change
      }
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunatley, I'm afraid I'm not sure how to make your code work.  The aspects of what I don't know how to do (make js and CSS interact) are kind of assumed in your code -- perhaps they seem obvious to you.  Would you be willing to edit this into working code?  Perhaps a JS Fiddle?  Thanks again.

Comment: Of course, it is not a perfect code, I just try to give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks very much for your helpful answer, which I accepted and upvoted.  This is a great example and widely useful.  I suspect that many others may benefit from this as well.

Comment: Also, is it possible in JS to get the current rotation position of the object?  Something like:     getPosition: function() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('theImage');
        ??
      },

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad that you found my answer helpful.

Comment: With elem.style you can get or set all css attributes, I'm not sure there is a javascript method for that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations can be helpful.