# smooth rotation javascript edge browser issue

Tags: javascript, css, animation, microsoft-edge, smoothing

Currently, I am trying to figure out on how to rotate an image in HTML smoothly.

There is an image. If a button is pressed, the image starts an ease-in rotate animation. When on max speed, it just keeps rotating until a stop-button is pressed. 
Following, the animation slowly stops, resulting in the image staying at a certain angle. Because (from what I know and tried) it is not possible, to make this kind of animation with CSS, I used an interval in JS which updates every 16 milliseconds. Here is the snippet:

```
        var counter = 0;
        var rotation = 0;
        var speedVal = 0.01;
        var speedFactor = 3;
        var spinInterval = setInterval(function () {
                rotation += counter * speedFactor;
                rotation = rotation % 360;
                if (counter != 0) $("#pumpIcon").css('transform', 'rotate(' + rotation + 'deg)');//set the image to a certain angle
                if (counter < pump.spinning) {
                    counter += speedVal;
                }
                else if (counter >pump.spinning) {
                    counter -= speedVal;
                }
                if (counter * 100 < 1) counter = 0;//This way, the animation will fully stop/not accelerate when it reached a certain value
            }
        }, 16);
```

There is a for loop because there are two seperate images spinning, so just ignore this fact.

The problem lies in using this kind of solution in the Edge browser: It seems as if the image is shaking and I guess its because JS is not meant to update the UI that frequently. It even seems to run not that smooth on certain, not so fast, devices(Meaning that if there is lots of scripts done in the background, which is every 6 seconds, it pauses the animation for a few milliseconds resulting in stutter.)

Is there any way to solve this problem? Some kind of "UI-Thread-like" thing in JS, or even better, a way to solve this problem in CSS? I really have no idea on how to deal with it, because a simple CSS-Animation won't do the trick.

Comment: Have you tried [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead of setTimeout/setInterval?

Comment: Thank you James for your answer, I changed to this approach because it fixes the stutter in browsers like Chrome and Firefox. However, the main problem(stutter in Edge, which is a different kind of stutter) remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could stop the CSS animation by using the animation-play-state property.

Please refer to the following sample:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .image {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            width: 120px;
            height: 120px;
            margin: -60px 0 0 -60px;
            -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
            -moz-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
            animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
        }

        @-moz-keyframes spin {
            100% {
                -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes spin {
            100% {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
        }

        @keyframes spin {
            100% {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="theImage" class="image" src="https://brainful.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/images/twoStates/circle.png" alt="">
    <button onclick="Rotate.start()">Start</button>
    <button onclick="Rotate.stop()">Stop</button>
    <button onclick="Rotate.setSpeed('1s')">Speed</button>
    <button onclick="Rotate.setEasing()">Earsing</button>
    <script>
        Rotate = {
            speed: 2,
            start: function () {
                var elem = document.getElementById('theImage');
                elem.style.animationPlayState = 'running';
            },
            stop: function () {
                var elem = document.getElementById('theImage');
                elem.style.animationPlayState = 'paused';
            }
        };
    </script>
</body>
```

Code from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31881559/css3-animation-for-rotation-of-an-image-with-parameters-controlled-by-javascrip).

If you want to change the speed, you could use Javascript to change the [transition-duration](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition.asp) property.

Comment: I modified your approach to match my needs and this solves the problem of stutter. Thank you!